# Pointers(?) crash the C program

Tags: c, pointers

I try to use a new struct for a dynamic "MapNode"s array, yet the program crashes:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000C191C in Astar.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

I call the getConnectedNodesArray function, which calls the other two functions.
I know it's some kind of pointers problem.
When I used copies of the data instead of trying to point to existing data in MapNode map[][12] it worked.

Thanks.

```
typedef struct MapNode * MapNodePointer;


typedef struct MapNode{
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    int traversable;
    double f;
    double g;
    double h;
    MapNodePointer parentNode;
}MapNode;


typedef struct MapNodesArray{
    MapNode* nodes;
    int size;
}MapNodesArray;

void addNodeToEnd(MapNodesArray* arr, MapNode* p) {
    arr->size++;
    arr->nodes = realloc(arr->nodes, arr->size * sizeof(MapNode*));
    (&(arr->nodes))[arr->size - 1] = p;
}

MapNodesArray* NewNodesArr() {
    MapNode *first = realloc(NULL, 0 * sizeof(MapNode));
    MapNodesArray temp = { first, 0 };
    return &temp;
}

MapNodesArray* getConnectedNodesArray(MapNodePointer node, MapNode map[][12]) {
    MapNodesArray* arr = NewNodesArr();
    addNodeToEnd(&arr, &map[node->x - 1][node->y - 1]);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Please post the Error message and where exactly the program crashes (which function call, etc). Also please first try to use your debugger to step through the program so you can pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Tip: Don't hide pointers behind typedefs. Also, `addNodesToEnd` looks dodgy...

Comment: @prq: Are you going to come and try to suggest edits to my copy of K&R too?

Comment: Also, do you want to store the nodes themselves or pointers to them in your `MapNodesArray`? Getting mixed signals there...

Comment: I want to store pointers to the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to fear indirection. Face it head-on and make sure you get exactly the amount you want:

```
typedef struct MapNode * MapNodePointer;
```

The above is a bad idea, because it hides the pointer-ness.

```
typedef struct MapNodesArray{
    MapNode* nodes;
    int size;
}MapNodesArray;
```

The above structure is no good for storing a dynmaic list of pointers to nodes. The `nodes`-member needs one more star: `MapNode** nodes;`

```
void addNodeToEnd(MapNodesArray* arr, MapNode* p) {
    arr->size++;
    arr->nodes = realloc(arr->nodes, arr->size * sizeof(MapNode*));
```

There's a better way to indicate the amount of memory you need: `arr->size * sizeof *arr->nodes` Always check for allocation failure. Bare-bones would be aborting the program. Insert here:

```
    if(!arr->nodes) abort();
```

The compiler will rightfully complain about the next line now, just remove the address-of-operator:

```
    (&(arr->nodes))[arr->size - 1] = p;
}

MapNodesArray* NewNodesArr() {
    MapNode *first = realloc(NULL, 0 * sizeof(MapNode));
```

The above line could be replaced with `MapNode* first = 0;`

```
    MapNodesArray temp = { first, 0 };
```

The above line defines an automatic variable, never return a pointer to that.

```
    return &temp;
}
```

oops. Complete rewrite:

```
MapNodesArray* NewNodesArr() {
    MapNodesArray temp* = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    *temp = (MapNodesArray){ 0, 0 };
    return temp;
}
```

Or even better:

```
MapNodesArray NewNodesArr() {
    return (MapNodesArray){ 0, 0 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how much memory do you think

```
MapNodesArray* NewNodesArr() {
    MapNode *first = realloc(NULL, 0 * sizeof(MapNode));
    MapNodesArray temp = { first, 0 };
    return &temp;
}
```

will allocate? (hint: none at all.)

Also, you're returning a pointer to a local variable (via `&temp`). That thing dies with the function return.

Comment: I know, but I had to initialize it.

Comment: @user2467223: How about initialising it to `(MapNode *)NULL`? Also, what about the pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope?

Comment: I edited the code. Also I used realloc so the local var wont die.

Comment: @user2467223 please don't remove/edit the original code in the question, If you need to make edits in your original question, please mark them as *Edit*, preferably under the original questions

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what EOF has said, also the line

```
(&(arr->nodes))[arr->size - 1] = p;
```

in function addNodeToEnd, will be writing the address p in a memory location outside the the nodes array. This will lead to memory corruption.

to illustrate
say variable 'nodes' has a memory address 0x00000002 and you have assigned a memory location say 0x00000050 through the call to realloc. The statement above takes the offset (arr->size-1) from 0x00000002 instead of taking it from 0x00000050. This is because you are taking the address of nodes by using &. Something of the form

```
(arr->nodes)[arr->size - 1] = p;
```

will take the offset from 0x00000050 which is what you seem to be needing.